# Creating Blender-like cavity shader

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader, godot

I'm trying to achieve in Godot something similar to cavity effect from Blender (this can be enabled in viewport options; cube on the left is displayed by viewport with this option enabled):

[image: blender cavity effect]

How would you replicate this?

Comment: This looks like a type of ambient occlusion effect. [You might want to try Godot's SSAO options](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/3d/environment_and_post_processing.html#screen-space-ambient-occlusion-ssao) to see if you can achieve something similar with that.

Comment: To me it looks like an edge detection shader applied ontop of the base color with a slight bleeding of white on the edge of each face.

Comment: I found something similar with shader code: http://madebyevan.com/shaders/curvature/

Answer (score 1):

Closest I've seen to recreating this effect as a shader

https://youtu.be/JMMy-xqrwdw
[image]